# Not able to open Attachments in Salesforce Lightning Chatter page iOS webview

Tags: react-native, salesforce, wkwebview, salesforce-chatter

All,

We are building a custom mobile app based on salesforce services in React native, As chatter functionality is huge we are loading the chatter lightning page in a Webview using "react-native-wkwebview-reborn".

Below is the URL used to load the Chatter page.

> ${APIUrls.SALESFORCE_HOST_URL}/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=${decodeURIComponent(this.props.accessToken)}&retURL=${encodeURIComponent(returnURL)}
>
> returnURL = ${SALESFORCE_LIGHTNING_HOST}/lightning/page/chatter

We are able to display the chatter page and it is working well, But when we click on any of the attachment, The attachment is not opening and the page is not scrolling as correctly.

The same functionality working perfectly in Andriod.

Any one suggest the reason for this.